# content_tag_for a collection in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Post model. Posts have many Comments. I want to generate a `<ul>` element for `post.comments` using `content_tag_for`.

Ideally, it'd produce

```
<ul id="comments_post_7" class="comments">  
...  
</ul>
```

where 7 is the ID of the Post.

The closest I can get uses

```
<% content-tag-for :ul post, :comments do %>
```

which produces

```
<ul id="comments_post_7" class="post">  
...  
</ul>
```

which is pretty close, except for the `class="post"`. Using `:class => :comments` in the `content_tag_for` yields `class="post comments"`, but I just want `class="comments"`.

It seems logical that I'd be able to use something like

```
<% content_tag_for :ul post.comments do %>
```

but, sadly, that yields

```
<ul id="array_2181653100" class="array">  
...  
</ul>
```

I've searched far and wide. I feel like I'm missing some elegant way to do this. Am I? Because, seriously, `<ul id="comments_post_<%= post.id %>" class="comments">` is painful.

Comment: There's a special way to mark code as code: with four spaces or using the button that reads 101 010, so that your code is highlighted and readable as everybody else's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use option of :id and :class

```
<% content_tag_for(:ul, post.comments, :id => "comments_post_#{post.id}", :class => "comments") do %>
  xxx
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks. I suppose this is a reasonable compromise. Still disappointed that I have to resort to this, though.

If I find myself using this pattern in other places, I'll probably factor it out into a helper as Shripad suggests below.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by extending @shingara's answer:
in the posts_helper.rb:

```
module PostsHelper
#This is specific only to your posts controller and only for your case!! 
#This can be made more generic though!

 def generate_ul(content)
   content_tag(:ul, content, :class => "comments", :id => "comments_post_#{post.id}")
 end
end
```

In your views:

```
<%=h generate_ul(post.comments) %>
```